# Can I install MSP_Common module using Magento Connect, although I haven't paid for anything?

Tags: module, magento-connect

I want to install MSP_Common module, in order to get my BancaSella module to work properly. Can I do this through Magento Connect or do I have to find another way? If I can install module using Magento Connect, then please help me know how to do this? I tried to access Magento Connect page by clicking on System -> Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager, but I am just redirected to htp://localhost/dashboard page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general answer for all extensions.
If you have the code you can install it manually on your magento instance. Going through Magento connect is not mandatory.
But it depends on how the archive with the code is built.
I remember that for older version of magento connect the archive with the code did not have all the files and folders in their right place. They were all in the root of the archive.
If this is true, you might have problems moving everything in the right place.
But I think in the newer version everything is where it should be and you just have to copy the unziped archive over your magento isntall. Make sure the `app` in the extension goes over the `app` folder of your install.
Same goes for the other folders you may have in there.

Clear the cache when you are done.

Comment: So this is a way to bypass Magento Connect that you are explaining, right? I want to install it using Magento Connect. So my question is, do I have to pay for it, or is it free and can be used as such?

Comment: I don't know how the extension is distributed. So I don't know if you have to pay for it. But you should not need to pay for accessing Magento Connect. that's for sure.

Comment: Ok. I am getting redirected to web server root for some reason, when I try to access magento connect. Do you know what can be the issue?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe you should ask a separate question for this. Your question here sounds really specific and tied to a certain module.

Comment: I got the code and installed it without much problems. So, at the end, I can just bypass the magento connect and like you said, manually copy over the module to my Magento.